# сортировка в groups.getMembers()

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Может, кому-то попадалось отсутствующее в [документации](http://vk.com/developers.php?o=-1&p=groups.getMembers) описание параметров сортировки метода [`groups.getMembers()`](http://vk.com/developers.php?o=-1&p=groups.getMembers):

**`time_asc`** и **`time_desc`** — правильно ли я понимаю, что это по сортировка времени, как давно чел. состоит в группе? Сомневаюсь, т.к. в моей группе, выходит, есть несколько чел. которые там дольше, чем я.

Answer (score 1):

```
time_asc
```

Ну так почему не посчитать самому?

Возьми время  и дату из контакта и отними от текущей, получишь  *как давно чел. состоит в группе*

Comment: «Возьми время и дату из контакта»
1) это как их можно взять, каким методом?
2) хочется просто понять, по какому принципу vk внутри себя там где-то сортирует юзеров, перед выдачей в этом методе.